# How to keep visualizations (i.e. draw('mpl')) displayed while other code is called

Tags: matplotlib, qiskit

I would like to be able to save and call a visualization, then have it show in-between other code. I know with MatPlotLib, you can do plt.show(), is there anything like that for Qiskit?

```
def test():
  return plot_bloch_multivector(circ)

print("This is what the plot looks like")
test()
print("See? Anyway...")
# more code
```

Output:

```
This is what the plot looks like
See? Anyway...
```

Desired  output:

```
This is what the plot looks like
# O O O (displayed bloch multivector)
See? Anyway...
```

I am using Google Colab (ver. 3.7.15).

Answer (score 0):

In any jupyter notebook (including Google Colab), you can display an object with `display`

```py
def test():
    return plot_bloch_multivector(circ)

print("This is what the plot looks like")
display(test())  # <----------------------
print("See? Anyway...")
```